# C# gives NullReferenceException while processing lists

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

The following code gives a NullReferenceException while processing. Can anyone tell me why its happening, and how to fix it? thanks in advance! this might be a very simple thing, I'm missing somewhere.

```
if (a.Count != 0)
 {
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in a )
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow newrow in b)
     {
        if( row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == newrow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() &&
            row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == newrow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) // this is the line that gives the error.
            {
                      a.Remove(row);
            }
          }
     }
}
```

the two lists have been declared at the top of the class so I don't know why its giving this error.

```
 List<DataGridViewRow> a = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

 List<DataGridViewRow> b = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
```

As suggested, I tried  using a for loop bit it still gives the same exception

here's the code

```
if (a.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = a.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                int index1 = i;


                for (int k = 0; k < b.Count; k++)
                {
                    int index2 = k;

                    if (a.ElementAt<DataGridViewRow> (index1).Cells[0].Value.ToString() == b.ElementAt<DataGridViewRow>(index2).Cells[0].Value.ToString() && a.ElementAt<DataGridViewRow>(index1).Cells[1].Value.ToString() == b.ElementAt<DataGridViewRow>(index2).Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                    {

                        a.RemoveAt(index1);

                    }
                    else continue;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the null pointer exception, use the debugger.  One of your variables is null.

But once that is fixed, you cannot modify a list while you are iterating over it.  The simplest solution in the code you've presented is to change your [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) loops into [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loops.

From the MSDN documentation for `foreach`:

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection. The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the desired information, **but should not be used to change the contents of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects**.

Comment: If he uses `for` instead of `foreach` the first element will be deleted successfully, but it would be a problem since he continues iterating through the list.

Comment: I've always found the simplest solution to handle the deletion from an enumeration is to take a local copy of the enumeration by calling the extension method ToArray(), then you can modify the original collection without a problem....eg foreach(DataGridViewRow row in a.ToArray() ){a.Remove(row);}

Comment: I had the for loop initialy, it was giving the same exception. I've added that code for the for loop to the question

Comment: @Xhalent: Good solution.  Also you can collect a list of rows to be removed after the `foreach` loops are over.

Comment: @Ozair: Good point.  More logic will have to be adjusted than simply changing the type of loops.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `null` `Value`, so `ToString()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

- `row.Cells[0]` is null
- `row.Cells[1]` is null
- `row.Cells[0].Value` is null
- `row.Cells[1].Value` is null

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/10/24/removing-items-in-a-list-while-iterating-through-it/) delete an element from a collection that you are iterating through. The solution is to store the list of elements to be deleted in another List, and then delete them in another iteration. Following is a solution.

```
    //New list that will contain the Objects to be deleted later on.
    List<DataGridView> listToDelete = new List<DataGridView>();

    if (a.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in a )
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow newrow in b)
            {
                if( row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == newrow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() &&
                row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == newrow.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                {
                    listToDelete.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (DataGridView d in listToDelete) {
        a.Remove(d);
    }
```